How to ignore parenthesis in a REGEXMATCH?
I am attempting to sum up values based on matching a substring. The issue I am running into is that the substring and string both have parenthesis and therefore the match is failing.
I have created a sample sheet to show the basics of what is going on.
A little more context, the idea is to sum up all the projects that have the same start but can have different - allocations.
Any help making E2 correctly find the 3 Innovation Lap (TEST) Projects but not the 1 Test Innovation Lab (TEST) Projects.
I tried a SUMIF but it did not allow the level of detail I wanted.

sheet is private

You should not link to data or other information that is essential to the understanding of the question, in part because links may become broken in time.

Thank you both for these suggestions. Sheet no longer private.

you need to escape them with backslash \
=REGEXMATCH(B21; "te\(\)st")


injected into the 2nd argument, it would be:
=REGEXMATCH(B21; REGEXREPLACE(C21; "(\(.+)(\))"; "\\$1\\$2"))


